# Related Field got invalid lookup: name with content_type__name

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have the following...

```
@receiver(post_save)
def po_save(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):

    Event.objects.get(content_type__name=sender.__name__)
```

Which gives the error: **Related Field got invalid lookup: name**.

It seems to have a problem with `content_type__name` however I'm use content_type has `name` what I'm I doing wrong?

Comment: Does Event have a ForeignKey to ContentType? Maybe you should post the model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#miscellaneous) for Django 1.8:

> The name field of django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType has
>   been removed by a migration and replaced by a property. That means
>   it’s not possible to query or filter a ContentType by this field any
>   longer.

Comment: Dam! I did however find out ``content_type__model`` matches ``.__name__.lower()`` of the class so that works.